# How to get the value of span from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the value of span from jquery  but it shows an errir like this

```
   TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
   http://localhost:10489/YellowPages/YellowPageHome.aspx?Menu=menu_cat_3594
   Line 328
```

I have a span like this

```
     <div  class="RatingAggregate" style="height: 25px; width: 25px;  margin: 5px;">
       <span id="AvgRt_1<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>">
        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Rating")%></span>
     </div>
```

I want to get the value of span like this

```
       var averageRatingValue = document.getElementById('AvgRt_1').innerHTML;
```

But shows the null error. hOw can i do this as i am trying to learn the jquery.

Comment: where the code is running on dom ready handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing wrong exactly

```
var averageRatingValue = document.getElementById('AvgRt_1').innerHTML;
```

Because you have not the id `AvgRt_1` but it is `AvgRt_1<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>`

So, try this jquery:

```
var averageRatingValue = $('span [id^=AvgRt_1]').html();
```

with javascript:

```
//define var for that
var spanId = '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>';
var averageRatingValue = document.getElementById('AvgRt_1' + spanId).innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your span has an `id` which concatenates the dataitem's `businessID`:

```
<span id="AvgRt_1<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>">
```

So the Id would look like: `AvgRt_1x` where `x` is your `BusinessID`

Secondly: you are not using jQuery as you mentioned. Just pure Javascript.

```
var averageRatingValue = document.getElementById('AvgRt_1').innerHTML;
```

Thirdly, you will have to specify the correct `id` either by way of hardcoded value if you know the exact `id` beforehand, or by way of a variable:

```
$('#AvgRt_1' + variable).text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put the `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>` in a *class*?

Then you can do:

```
var businessId = '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.BusinessID")%>';
$('#AvgRt_1.' + businessId).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply get it like, you can also use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
 $('span[id^="AvgRt_1"]').text() or or $('span').html()
```

For Particulr span

```
 $('span #SPANID').text()
```

Comment: in my page there are lots of spans and i want to get the particular span text

Comment: @Arunesh, you can use `$('span #SPANID').text()`